# how to draw the graph of this function with rationals and irrationals

Tags: calculus

if someone can draw the graph of this function for me, thank you
[image]

I tried something like this but I'm not sure;

[image]

Comment: Can you draw $\sqrt[3]{x}$ for $x \in \mathbb R$?

Comment: Obviously it's not really possible to do accurately. I would just draw the graphs of $\sqrt[3]{x}$ and $-\sqrt[3]{x}$, maybe making the curves dashed to show that neither form a complete unbroken curve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graph of your function will look like this:

[image: Graph]

Note that this function is (seriously) discontinuous at all points $x \neq 0$, because $\mathbb{Q}$ lies dense in $\mathbb{R}$, i.e. every interval $(a- \epsilon, a+\epsilon)$ contains a rational number for every $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\epsilon>0$. Because of this, the function will "jump" between the red and blue graph infinitely often in any (no matter how small) interval you choose.

If you like to read more about fuctions with this kind of property, I recommend https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_function.

Answer (score 1):

When drawing graphs such as this, there is a convention that the points on the irrational part of the curve are drawn more closely together than the points on the rational part of curve. This is to emphasise that the cardinality of the irrationals is greater than that of the rationals. This might not seem like an 'accurate' sketch, but, when you think about it, the graphs of functions are never drawn accurately anyway.